# Where can I ask about developer tools and specifically developer tools on Windows?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

I'm a developer (relatively new) in a Windows 10 environment. Many times I find it difficult to find a windows version for common programming tools available for Linux or Mac. 
Where would be an appropriate place to ask questions related to this matter? 
I tried asking about a tool for Windows once at Stackoverflow, and my question was down voted, as it had to do with tool recommendation. 
I know this might be slightly off topic even here in meta.stackoverflow.com. However I find it really frustrating, as I have no where to ask and get answers about this topic.

Answer (score 2):

If you're *just* looking for tools, Stack Overflow isn't going to be the place that can help you.  We don't want to have recommendation lists, especially given that "common programming tools" is such a broad thing, that the only real intersection I've seen is "a good text editor".

If you're asking about a *specific* tool, that's more on-topic.  However, it depends on how you ask that, too; if you're asking how to use a specific tool, that's too broad.

This is one of those things that you're going to need to research on your own and gain some traction with.  We can't tell you what's going to be best for your work environment, since we're not in your work environment.  All we can do is make recommendations, which is what we want to *avoid*.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a specific question about a specific tool that's used primarily for programming, that's on-topic here.

If you're looking for recommendations, try Software Recommendations SE. (Tool recommendation requests got banned on SO awhile back because they're difficult to moderate well).

Comment: So how to use a specific tool is on topic here at meta.stackoverflow.com or at SO itself?

Comment: @Ben On Stack Overflow itself. Obviously, you'll want to be more specific than "how do I use this tool?", though, and SO is exclusively for programming tools. (Other software questions should be directed to Super User or Server Fault).